# Catch dropdown selection changes in Angularjs ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How to catch dropdown selection changes in ui-grid. I've customised 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor' like this

```
var customCellTemplate = '<div><form name=\"inputForm\"><select ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid" ui-grid-edit-dropdown ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\" ng-change="vm.onDropdownChange(row)" ng-options=\"field[editDropdownIdLabel] as field[editDropdownValueLabel] CUSTOM_FILTERS for field in editDropdownOptionsArray\"></select></form></div>'
```

Added **ng-change="vm.onDropdownChange(row)"** in ui-grid/dropdownEditor but onDropdownChange event not fired.

And my controller looks like this

```
function Controller(){
    vm.onDropdownChange = onDropdownChange;        

    vm.gridOption.columnDefs = [
        {
            field: 'staus', displayName: 'Status', editableCellTemplate: customCellTemplate, width: '20%',
            cellFilter: status filter, editDropdownIdLabel: 'status_id', editDropdownValueLabel: 'status', editDropdownOptionsArray: statusArray
        }, 
        {
          //Other fileds
        }];

    function onDropdownChange(row){

    }
}
```

Please tell me where i'm going wrong and how to accomplish this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use appScope to trigger your function.

Have a look [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope)

```
grid.appScope.onDropdownChange();
```